# Count(*) of a query having a LIMIT

Tags: sql, count, limit, mariadb

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT users.*, users_oauth.* FROM users LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id WHERE (
(MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('"+smith "+john"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ) 
ORDER BY user_date_accountcreated DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

Is there any way to get the `COUNT(*)` of this query ignoring the `LIMIT 0,50` in this same query ?
Or do I have to do 2 queries, one for the results, one for the COUNT(*) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can put everything in one query by adding a subquery for the count(). But internally it will be opening the table twice. Are you trying to page the output?

Comment: You are looking for `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  See:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MariaDB version is 10.2.0+ then window functions are supported and you can use `COUNT(*) OVER ()`:

```
SELECT 
  users.*, 
  users_oauth.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS countall
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id 
WHERE 
  MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('"+smith "+john"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY user_date_accountcreated DESC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

If your MariaDB version is 10.2.0- (prior to that) you could use a nested select within a column:

```
SELECT 
  users.*, 
  users_oauth.*,
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM users 
   LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id 
   WHERE MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('"+smith "+john"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  ) AS countall
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id 
WHERE 
  MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('"+smith "+john"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY user_date_accountcreated DESC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 1):

The  limit is not a problem  problem  if you need the count(*) repated on each row you can add a column with the related query

```
SELECT users.*, users_oauth.* , (select count(*) FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id 
        WHERE (
          (MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('"+smith "+john"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ) )
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id 
WHERE (
  (MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('"+smith "+john"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ) 
ORDER BY user_date_accountcreated DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

but if you want only add count(*)  to the columns selected   in some mysql version you get only a row 
and in others you have error because are mixin aggregate function and single column without declare a group by clause